# Can't install Nokogiri gem, "libxml/parser.h" not found, but its there, why?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, libxml2

I tried to install Nokogiri but I always get an compiling error:

```
checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
```

but, I've installed it and all other dependencies.

I try to give the installer hints like this:

```
%> gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-lib=/usr/lib/ --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2/

...

checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***

...
```

but it still doesn't install:

```
%> find /usr/include/ -name "parser.h"    
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h
...
```

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Output of:

"[`dpkg-query -l | grep xml`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kKq6wcQi)" and "[`dpkg-query -l | grep xslt`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=XdtqWMKG)"

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The failure seem to be on the side of GCC:

```
%> cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
   printf("Hello World \n");
}

%> gcc hello.c
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'
collect2: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what operating system this is.

Comment: Trying a different approach - you should have an `mkmf.log` file from the directory where the install failed. Can you show us the contents of that file? Also - do you have the build tools and compilers installed on your system? `extconf.rb` might be attempting to do test building. Try to run something like `gcc` or `make` from the command line, see if they respond.

Comment: I think you truly don't have them installed. Did you install them using `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev`?

Comment: Hmm, I ran into similar issue on Mac OSX today for nokogiri 1.5.2

Comment: Looks like the libraries are not correct for the architecture. Could you run: 1. `which gcc`, 2.`dpkg-query -S "crt1.o"|grep "/crt1.o"`. Are you on x64?

Comment: This question should be re-opened. I had this issue using ubuntu 13.04 on an Amazon ec2 instance.  I think a large number of people could be helped by this question as I was.

Answer (score 22):

This will work.

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: might have to uninstall nokogirl and/or libxml-ruby first ala: gem uninstall nokogiri; gem uninstall libxml-ruby; then reinstall

Comment: I keep getting this error and having to use this solution everytime I try to run a Rails 3 app.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced the same issue on (`cat /etc/centos-release`:) CentOS release 6.6 (Final).

```
sudo yum install -y rubygem-nokogiri
```

…fixed that problem.

(see: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#red_hat___centos)

Comment: I got away with `yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel` (on CentOS 6.7).  I don't have the system Ruby installed, so this saves me having to install a bunch of Ruby-related dependencies.